# Сравнение количества вхождений одного значение в двух разных списках

Tags: python

Есть 2 отсортированных списка в котором рабочие бренды и нерабочие, также результирующий список:

```py
good_brands = ['2XU', '2XU', '7 For All Mankind', '7 For All Mankind Kids', 'A2 by Aerosoles', 'ABLE', 'ADA Collection', 'Acorn', 'Acorn Kids', 'Adam Lippes', 'Adelyn Rae']
not_work_brands = ['1.STATE', '2(X)IST', '24th & Ocean', '2XU', '34 Heritage', '361 Degrees', '42 GOLD', '4Ward Clothing', '6 Shore Road by Pooja', 'BYBI (4)']
bad_brands = []
```

Нужно сравнить одинаковые значения в списках и если кол-во одинакового значения в good_brands больше, чем в not_work_brands, тогда в bad_brands мы его не добавляем

Например, в good_brands '2XU' два раза встречается, а в not_work_brands один раз, значит результат должен получится примерно такой:

```py
bad_brands = ['1.STATE', '2(X)IST', '24th & Ocean', '34 Heritage', '361 Degrees', '42 GOLD', '4Ward Clothing', '6 Shore Road by Pooja', 'BYBI (4)']
```

Кол-во одинаковых брендов может быть разное как в одном так и в другом списке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set соберет все уникальные значения, а дальше из них выберем те, которые встречаются в первом списке реже, чем во втором

```
res = [x for x in set(good_brands + not_work_brands) \
        if good_brands.count(x) - not_work_brands.count(x) < 1]
```

Comment: По-хорошему лучше сначала посчитать все повторяющиеся элементы в двух списках (это по одному проходу по двум спискам). В текущей реализации при вызове `count` происходит полный проход по каждому из списков.

Comment: если встанет вопрос про эффективность, то метод count всяко плох, тут и спорить не про что